# JHtmlArea - 'this' is undefined in 'loaded' function

Tags: jquery, jhtmlarea

I'm using JHtmlArea in my page and want to add a callback function to be executed after the control has been loaded. The documentation [here](https://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Editor%20%22Load%22%20Event%20Callback) is quite explicit that inside the callback function, `this` should refer to the JHtmlArea object. However, I am finding that is is `undefined`.

This simple test code:

```
$('#NoteText').htmlarea({
    loaded: function(){
        alert(this);
    }
});
```

Alerts 'undefined'.

I'm using jHtmlArea v0.7.5, JQuery 1.11 and IE10.

How can I get a reference to the jHtmlArea in the loaded callback?

Comment: You may have found a bug in that library (or it could be some setting that you haven't set properly, I don't know the library). You can set a breakpoint with dev tools inside your `loaded` callback, and then step back in the call stack to see how it's called and with what context, and then trace back from there to see if there's a mistake in how they set the context for the callback.

Comment: I've found that by changing alert(this); to alert(this.editor);, "[object]" is displayed. So it seems the parent object appears as undefined, but I can get at its child properties? Maybe it's a JavaScript quirk, however this does now allow me to do what I need to do.

Comment: Works there http://jsfiddle.net/c8e8k084/  FYI, don't use alert() in debugging purpose

Comment: Neglected to mention we are using JQuery 1.11. Update the Fiddle to use that (or > 1.8.3) and you get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined".

Comment: Sounds like that might be caused by the fact that the deprecated `$.browser` jQuery property was removed in v1.9.